# “Dans le weekend” or “pendant le weekend”?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, indications-de-temps

I don't know what's the correct grammar for below sentence:

> Je pratique la natation dans le weekend.

or

> Je pratique la natation pendant le weekend.

Answer (score 6):

Both are grammatically correct, but the first one should be avoided.

"Pendant" clearly indicate a time localization, whereas "dans" indicates usually a spatial localization (there are exceptions). By using "dans" you are still grammatically correct but only because of the vagueness of "dans". Don't do that.

Other possibilities are using the synonym "durant", or simply:

> Je pratique la natation le weekend.

as "weekend" is obviously a time localization.

However there is another problem in your sentences. You use indicative present but in these sentences what it means is very ambiguous. Is it an habit ? An enunciation ? Close future ? Nothing in the sentence give any clue.

Comment: Je ne pense pas que "pratiquer la natation dans le weekend" soit grammaticalement correct ! Je ne l'ai jamais entendu et comme tu le dis si bien *dans* est une préposition de **lieu**, or le weekend n'est pas un lieu...

Comment: @tlombart contre exemple: "Je te répond dans l'heure" :)

Comment: @Random en effet, tout comme "je suis dans les temps", cependant ce sont des expressions qui ont un sens figuré, ici je crois qu'on s'intéresse au sens littéral, et si "je te réponds dans le weekend" pourrait se dire, je ne vois pas "nager dans le weekend" être correct... encore une fois c'est basé sur le fait que je n'ai jamais entendu telle utilisation de *dans*...

Comment: @tlombart "J'irai à la piscine dans la semaine" se dit assez couramment de par chez moi, en France. Cependant, "dans" apporte ici une notion de vague / flou. On sait que la personne ira à la piscine dans la semaine, mais on ne sait pas si la date est fixée.

Comment: @Nico il y a bien une différence, dans ton exemple, tu dis "j'irai" au futur. Là, "je pratique" est au présent et implique une habitude, qui ne correspond donc pas à la même chose...

Comment: @Random C'est pour cela que mon commentaire n'est pas une réponse : il ne concerne pas l'exemple donné, il permet simplement d'approfondir l'usage de cette expression.

Comment: @tlombart Je suis conscient du fait que "dans" soit parfois utilisé pour une localisation temporelle, mais aussi que c'est une mauvaise habitude que de le faire quand on peut exprimer plus précisément ce qu'on veut dire. Je pense que ma réponse telle qu'elle est assez claire dans ce sens.

Comment: @Random: Je ne suis pas sûr que l'OP parle ici d'une habitude. On peut supposer aussi bien un futur proche.

Answer (score 2):

En fait, ça dépend !

Si tu parles au **passé** de ce que tu as fait le week end tu vas dire

*If you talk about something you did this week-end*

> J'ai pratiqué la natation ce week end

ou

> J'ai fait de la natation ce week end

Si tu veux dire que **tous les week end** tu fais de la natation, tu dis alors

*If you used to swim every week end*

> Je pratique la natation le week end

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact both of your attempts are quite odd, it would have helped if you would have told what you precisely intend to say but assuming you want "I practice swimming during the weekend", I would suggest:

- *Je fais de la natation le week-end.*
- *Je pratique la natation le week-end.*
- *J'ai mes entraînements de natation le week-end.*
- *Je travaille ma natation/ma brasse/mon crawl le week-end.*

or simply:

- *Je nage le week-end.*

Note that there is no need to translate "during", *le week-end* is enough.

Answer (score -4):

"Je pratique la natation durant le week-end".
"Je pratique la natation pendant le week-end" is good also, but usage for this kind of sentence is beter with "durant" ;-)