# Time phrases- during/at/in

Tags: vocabulaire

With time phrases, how would you say,
‘During/at or in the weekend?’ Would it be, “à le weekend’, “dans le weekend”, “en le weekend”, “pendant le weekend,” or something else? By the way, it doesn’t JUST have to be ‘the weekend.’ This question can be for summer holidays, Monday night, in the future or any other time phrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“Dans le weekend” or “pendant le weekend”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19415/dans-le-weekend-or-pendant-le-weekend) , https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/sur-le-weekend-vs-le-weekend

Answer (score 0):

> - You never would say "à le weekend" as you always have to use the corresponding contracted form for "**à le**", that is to say "**au**". However "au weekend" is not used to say "pendant le weekend".
> - You never would say "<s>dans le weekend</s>"

1/ *specification of a usual time*

- **pendant** le weekend, **durant** le weekend, **tous** les weekends
- **au cours** du weekend (*this locution does not mean "during" but "at a certain time during"*)

  - On se voit **pendant** le weekend. (pendant l'été, les jours fériés,…)
  - Ils se rencontrent **tous** les weekends. (tous les étés,…)
  - **Le** weekend il y a beaucoup de monde. (L'été, **En** été, *however never* "**En** printemps",   *however never* "**en** weekend", *never* "**en** les jours fériés",…)
  - Elle fait ce travail d'habidude **au cours** du weekend.

2/ *specification of a time that is coming next as a first re-occurrence*

- **pendant** le weekend, **durant** le weekend, **ce** weekend, **ce** weekend-**ci**
- **au cours** du weekend (*this locution does not mean "during" but "at a certain time during"*)

  - L'équipe va faire une randonnée **pendant** le weekend.
  - Nous y penserons **ce** weekend.
  - Nous le ferons **ce** weekend-**ci**. (*so as to be more specific*)
  - **Au cours** du weekend il fera une partie de golf.